# Mysql select years from rows that have a gap of 5 years

Tags: mysql

```
+------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2  |
+------+-------+
| 0    | 2008  |
| 0    | 2013  |
| 1    | 2014  |
| 1    | 2015  |
| 0    | 2020  |
| 0    | 2021  |
| 0    | 2022  |
+------+-------+
```

If I have a table result that has the above data. Using Mysql, how can I select the years that have a gap of 5 years and over where col1 in the lower year equals 1?
e.g return the row with 2020
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Col2` is unique:

```
select min(t2.Col2)
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.Col2 > t1.Col2
where t1.Col1 = 1
group by t1.Col2
having min(t2.Col2) >= t1.Col2 + 5
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b80b/1)

Comment: this is an interesting approach and works in the above scenario but wouldn't work in a more generalized scenario. For example, if you add two more data points `(1, 2020), (1, 2030)`, it will falsely return the `2030` point, even though that should not be in the results. To be honest, I'm not sure how the above would be accomplished in SQL (I'd do it myself in code), but I'm sure there is some query that can accomplish the "n+1" feature the question is asking about.

Comment: @David542 This query wouldn't return 2030 in your scenario (http://rextester.com/CAAYE77163). This is because the following entry after 2020 is 2021, which is dermined correctly by this query (see the unfiltered version: http://rextester.com/TNJW65649).

Comment: you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I missed the 2021 point in the data.

Answer (score 0):

select sc1.col2 from table_name sc1, table_name sc2
where sc1.col2 > sc2.col1 group by sc1.col1 HAVING sc1.col2>=sc1.col1+5;